# linux stress, impose work on specific disks

Tags: centos, raid, io, raid0

Have a server running centos 7.6, and it has 4 ssd's as Raid-0 mounted as `/scratch/`

I have the linux program `stress-1.0.4-16` and I just learned `stress-ng` existed.

Is there a way with `stress` to tell it to do I/O operations to stress a specific set of disks such as my 4 disk Raid-0?  Or does it only work on whatever the root file system is such as `/tmp`?  And if that's the case I've done `systemctl enable tmp.mount` which means the `/tmp` folder is no longer on disk negating the disk i/o function of stress ?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to `cd` to a directory in the disk drive you want to stress. Using `-v` option confirms it creates the stress files on the current directory.

```
# stress -v -d 1 
stress: info: [29736] dispatching hogs: 0 cpu, 0 io, 0 vm, 1 hdd
stress: dbug: [29736] using backoff sleep of 3000us
stress: dbug: [29736] --> hoghdd worker 1 [29737] forked
stress: dbug: [29737] seeding 1048575 byte buffer with random data
stress: dbug: [29737] opened ./stress.yPWMGk for writing 1073741824 bytes
stress: dbug: [29737] unlinking ./stress.yPWMGk
stress: dbug: [29737] fast writing to ./stress.yPWMGk
```

I also suggest you use `fio` instead if you need a more accurate tool.